# how to delete wordpress customized notification?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, notifications

I have created WordPress plugin that sends notification when user clicks specific button to a dashboard page I have created ,and the problem I am facing is that I can dismiss the notification from the dashboard page but when I refresh the page it shows up again ,is there a way to delete it after I see it from that page??

Comment: After the user dismiss de notification you are saving this information in any database? I think the plugin isn't know that user saw the notification.

Comment: i created a dismissible notification but when the page refresh it shows up again , so what i need is that after the user dismisses a notification ,the notification gets deleted @GabrielaMendes

Comment: I think you need to persiste this dismiss action in somewhere. The best way is save in a data base like in this example: https://www.alexgeorgiou.gr/persistently-dismissible-notices-wordpress/
He save this info in the database, so the plugin will know if the user already dismisses the notification.
You can also save it to localStorage, but I don't think it's a good practice, as the user will change computers or cell phones and the notification will appear to him again.